# Xamarin Device Provisioning problems on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I installed Xamarin Studio on my Mac and created a HelloWorld iOS project and it does not compile, it showed error "No installed provisioning profiles match the installed ios code signing keys", pointing to Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets file. Though this same project works in visual studio.

I googled around and found in docs https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/free-provisioning/ I followed the steps to open my xCode > Preferences > Accounts > then choosing my AppleID and View Details but it does not show any Provisioning Profiles in this window even though I clicked on Create next to iOS Development, all that did was it created a certificate iPhone Developer in my keychain. I want to mention I don't have an actual device like iphone or ipad, I'm just trying to get the code working in emulator first.  I also went to developer.apple.com but didn't see the screens as to where I could config these profiles.

What I'm using: Xamarin Studio Community 5.10.3, El Capitan, xCode 7.3.1

So what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: If you go to step 8 in your link does xcode say no provisioning profile with the option to fix issue?

Comment: Did you try clicking 'Download' once you go to your account details within Xcode? If so, I would restart your machine after doing that, rebuild the project, and try again

Comment: You can usually just ignore provisioning profiles if you delete the "Bundle Identifier" in info.plist. That worked for me to deploy to the simulator last time I tried (few weeks ago). Then make sure you are targeting `iPhoneSimulator` for your build and deploy.